# Automating Excel Autofilter with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am using the following VBA currently but am needing to build on it a little.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFilterData()
Dim wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
With wsData
    On Error Resume Next
    '//Reset Autofilter
    .ShowAllData
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 2,
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1")
End With
 '//Close my objects
Set wsData = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I run the above code, the filter returns zero results even though the cell H1 is populated and matches values in the 2nd column in the Master tab. In addition to utilizing H1 as part of the filter, I need to  be able to add additional Autofilter criteria from the "Summary-LT BD" tab using cells Q4-Q11 IF a value has been selected, If and of Q4-Q11="" then I need all values for that criteria to be shown. I will eventually add this macro to a button click in excel as a detailed view of some table values.

TIA for any help!

Jesse

Comment: First off, start by removing `On Error Resume Next`, then try running your code again. If nothing's happening you might just be getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

So I kind of put something together. I am pretty close. So the first 3 auto filters work great. my issue now is that when I leave a value blank in one of the q ranges, (which would be when I want no filter on that value) I am getting a blank output. I am assuming I need some sort of if "", show "*" type of statement in there somehow.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub NeedIn()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    With wsData
        On Error Resume Next
        '//Reset Autofilter
        .ShowAllData
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 23, "Inside LT"
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 75, "Need Date Moved In"
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 2, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 4, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q4").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 3, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q5").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 5, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q6").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 6, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q7").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 7, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q8").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 8, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q9").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 9, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q10").Value
        wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 10, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("Q11").Value

        Sheets("Master").Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    End With
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    With wsData
        On Error Resume Next
        '//Reset Autofilter
        .ShowAllData
     '//Close my objects
    End With
    Set wsData = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFilterData()
Dim wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

wsData.Range("$A$1:$BZ$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1")

'if you want to use multiple criteria to filter then you would have to use something like below (using an array of values to filter):
'wsData.Range("$A$1:$BZ$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

This will let you choose multiple fields/columns to filter with multiple Criteria:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFilterData()
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim H1Value As String

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'wsData.Range("$A$1:$BZ$" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1")

'Or to filter multiple fields/columns then the code below will do it
H1Value = Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1").Value
With wsData
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A1:BZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter
.Range("A1:BZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=H1Value
.Range("A1:BZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:="Inside LT"
.Range("A1:BZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=75, Criteria1:="Other"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried what you had but no luck yet. If I used multiple criteria it would need to be from different columns. Here is an example, though I know not set up correctly I think you will get what I am trying to do.                                                                                                                    wsData.Range("$A$1:$BZ$1").AutoFilter Field:=Array(2,23,75) Criteria1:=Array(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-LT BD").Range("H1"), "Inside LT", "Other"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: Updated my answer with something that will let you do what you expect, you can't simply add an array for the number of fields you are going to filter,...Please check my answer and let me know how you get on...